# how to load a file into a mysql table for a particular column?

Tags: mysql

I need to load a file into mysql table for a particular column I have a table cc with 2 columns name and points, I have to update only the points column, I have a txt called point.txt which has only the points,now I need to load the point.txt into the table cc for the particular column(pionts) this command is for a whole table.

```
load data local infile '/path/point.txt' into table tablename;`
```

I need to load the data for a particulate column

Comment: If `point.txt` does not have data uniquely identifying the row in `cc` (presumably, this would be `name`), then how would you plan on mapping the data in `point.txt` to the correct rows in `cc`? You need some mechanism to tie the data in your text file to specific rows in `cc`.

Comment: `LOAD` into a separate table, then do `UPDATE` to copy the column over.

Answer (score 1):

Manual states:
You can also discard an input value by assigning it to a user variable and not assigning the variable to a table column:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'
  INTO TABLE t1
  (column1, @dummy, column2, @dummy, column3);
```

So in your case, it may look something like:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/point.txt' INTO TABLE tablename (@dummy, points);
```